# How to reduce redundant coding in java?

Tags: java, python, optimization

```
public static byte[] sendRequest(String url ,Object params ,boolean isHttps){
        if(isHttps){
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)newURL(url).openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
       }

        }else{
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

        }


}
```

In this both if and else contains same lines of code beside type casting . If I move this lines of code to a common method again I want to type cast and do this process again . How can i reduce this redudant lines can anyone help me .

I have a solution in python .

```
     //pseudo code .
     if(isHttps) :
           urlConnection = https . 
     else : 
         urlConnection = http .
     urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
     urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
     urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
     urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
```

Because in python variable inside a if also accessible from outside block . In java how can i do this .

Comment: do the same thing in jave , it will work

Comment: isn't your "HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();" line the same in both cases?

Comment: I think kannan did not know that he could declare a variable before the if block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the `isHttps` variable check is there for a reason(?) and therefore the second cast should actually be `HttpURLConnection`, meaning there is a typo in the question?
If so the most methods used in the question are available in the parent class `URLConnection` without a cast, but not all.

Fortunately HttpsURLConnection is a subclas of HttpUrlConnection so just always casting to that will work here, replace all with (no need for the isHttps check):

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Hi all thanks a lot for your answers . Sorry for my Negligence . 

From my question 


else{
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
            
        }
its not HttpsUrlConnection it's HttpUrlConnection .

Answer (score 3):

Simple

```
public static byte[] sendRequest(String url ,Object params ,boolean isHttps){
     HttpsURLConnection urlConnection;
     if(isHttps){
         urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)newURL(url).openConnection();
      }else{
         urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
      }
         urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
         urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
         urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
         urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
         urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
         urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = isHttps
                                 ? (HttpsURLConnection)newURL(url).openConnection()
                                 : (HttpsURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();

urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
// etc.
```

The advantage of this over the "declare the variable before the `if`" approach is that this will work even if the variable is `final`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the variable declaration before the if block

```
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection;
if (isHttps) {
    urlConnection= (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
} else {
    urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
}
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable before the if statement, and assign 'null' to it (to avoid warnings that the variable might be uninitialized). Then follow the style in your pseudo-code example.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between the two blocks? Just use:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
```

You type-cast does nothing special. The `HttpsURLConnection` is a subclass of `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: Sorry for the typo .

Else block is not HttpsURLConnection it is HttpUrlConnection.

Comment: still does not really matter. A type cast does not really do anything with the objects you are casting. The code above should work, as `HttpsURLConnection` is a subclass of `HttpURLConnection`, so there is no if-statement needed.